# I have a crash when I want to show a "StackPanel" in "Storyboard" of a "DocPanel" in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio

I am trying to show a menu page after clicking in the HomePage button but I have problem, I have a crash when I click on the "HomePage", and crash say that it can not find "HomePage" name. I have searched a lot but did not find any thing.

```
    <Grid Background="#FF303B61">
        <StackPanel x:Name="HomePage" Background="#FF06063A" Width="150" Margin="150,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        </StackPanel>
        <DockPanel>
            <Canvas>
                <StackPanel Background="#FF06063A" Width="150" Margin="-101,0,0,0">
                    <StackPanel.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                                        <BeginStoryboard>
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="HomePage" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" Duration="0:0:5" From="100" To="500" />
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </BeginStoryboard>
                                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                                </EventTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </StackPanel.Style>
                    <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <Label Content="Label_1" Foreground="White" Width="91" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,0,10" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <Image Source="Images/Home.png"  Width="32" Height="28" Margin="0,10,7,10" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                        <DockPanel.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="DockPanel">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </DockPanel.Style>
                    </DockPanel>
                </StackPanel>
                <Border Background="#FF15184D">
                    <Grid/>
                </Border>
            </Canvas>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I want show this

```
<StackPanel x:Name="HomePage" Background="#FF06063A" Width="150" Margin="150,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            </StackPanel>
```

by click on Home page

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                                        <BeginStoryboard>
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="HomePage" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" Duration="0:0:5" From="100" To="500" />
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </BeginStoryboard>
                                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                                </EventTrigger>
```

[image]

my crash is:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You [can't use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.triggerbase.enteractions?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) `TriggerBase.EnterActions` with `EventTrigger`.

Add the `BeginStoryboard` directly to the trigger:

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeftButtonDown">      
  <BeginStoryboard>
   <Storyboard>
      <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="HomePage" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" Duration="0:0:5" From="100" To="500" />
    </Storyboard>
 </BeginStoryboard>
</EventTrigger>`
```